# Applescript run on relative path

Tags: path, applescript, latex

I'm running a quite stupid app, to clean my latex output files.
I'd like to place that app in every latex project i have, and be able to run that app. The app should detect its location based on where it is placed:
Ex: `/Users/User/Documents/LatexProject1/clean.app` to clean `.../LatexProject1` Folder.

So far, I managed to run a script, based on absolute paths, which is quite annoying, having to change the app's path every time i run a new Latex project.

Can you help me to edit my code?

```
set subfolderOfSharedFolder to quoted form of "Users/lukas/Google Drive/006 semester/00_Bachelorarbeit/00_Documentation"

set response to display dialog "Trash all of the output files in your latex folder?" buttons {"Yes, I'm ready", "No"} default button 2 cancel button 2 with title "<subfolder name> Folder Prep" with icon caution

if button returned of response is "Yes, I'm ready" then
    -- run spotlight search
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.lot c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell


    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.out c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell

    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.aux c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell

    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.blg c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell

    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.bbl c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell


    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.glg c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell


    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.glo c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell


    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.gls c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell


    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.idx c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell


    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.ist c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell


    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.lof c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell


    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.log c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell


    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.gz c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell


    -- run spotlight search 2
    set filesToDelete to paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == *.toc c' -onlyin " & subfolderOfSharedFolder)

    -- convert posix paths to file specifiers
    repeat with thisFile in filesToDelete
        set (contents of thisFile) to POSIX file thisFile
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        delete filesToDelete
    end tell

    if button returned of (display dialog "The APP files have been trashed." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "SuchAndSuch Folder Prep" with icon 1) is "OK" then
    end if
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

"`Path to me`" gives the path to the script itself. Since you want the enclosing folder, you would use something like

```
tell application "Finder"
    return folder of (path to me)
end tell
```

*Edit* to add:  You would convert this line

```
set subfolderOfSharedFolder to quoted form of "Users/lukas/Google Drive/006 semester/00_Bachelorarbeit/00_Documentation"
```

to something like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set subfolderOfSharedFolder to POSIX path of (folder of (path to me) as text)
end tell
```

assuming that you put the script you want to run in the folder `"Users/lukas/Google Drive/006 semester/00_Bachelorarbeit/00_Documentation"`

Comment: okay thanks. could you code my those 2-3 lines, i dont know how to embed those lines so they can work here:set subfolderOfSharedFolder to quoted form of "Users/lukas/Google Drive/006 semester/00_Bachelorarbeit/00_Documentation"

Comment: What is it you need? The path to the folder containing the script, in Unix format?